# Need help proving an identity envolving expected value of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove the following identity, stated in Bertsekas's Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition, pg. 114:

If $A_1,...,A_n$ are disjoint events that form a partition of the sample space, with P$(A_i)>0$ for all $i$, then
$$\text{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)E[X|A_i]$$

Things I know that may be useful:

- $\text{E}[X|A]=\sum_{x}xP_{X|A}(x)$
- $P_{X}{(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)P_{X|A_i}(x)$, where $A_1,...,A_n$ are disjoint events that form a partition of the sample space

This is what I've gotten so far (which isn't much):

\begin{align}
E[X]&=\sum_{x}xP_{X}(x)\\
&=\sum_{x}x[\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)P_{X|A_i}(x)]\\
&=\sum_{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)P_{X|A_i}(x)x
\end{align}

I've tried to expand the double summation but it didn't seem to lead anywhere. Can someone help? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Try swapping the summations.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of the summations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, actually.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname E [X] &= \sum_x \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname P (A_i) \operatorname P_{X\vert A_i}(x) x \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_x \operatorname P (A_i) \operatorname P_{X\vert A_i}(x) x \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname P (A_i) \sum_x x \operatorname P_{X\vert A_i}(x)  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname P(A_i) \operatorname E [X \vert A_i]
\end{align}$$